# PhoneGap Build For Windows Phone Prevents Javascript

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, phonegap-build, xap

I have developed one app in Visual Studio 2010 by using Cordova 1.7.0 template.

When I build this app in PhoneGap then everything working fine for android.

But for Windows Phone when I deploy the app.xap file in Windows phone then javascript stops working. even alert message is not working.

When I connect the Windows Phone to Visual Studio then every thing working fine in device as well as Windows Phone emulator.

Comment: Does it work with the latest build of WP7? I know a lot of changes have been going into the windows and blackberry platforms lately...I'd try it on the latest build (3.1.0rc1)ish first.

Comment: No PhoneGap build is not working for WP7.